# Hide tt_content elements in backend based on field value

Tags: php, configuration, typo3, children

```
<?php
```

I have a custom CType called theme_section_columns which has children records also from the tt_content table.
The relation parent -> child is made using the field tx_theme_tt_content.
This is the configuration:

```
$tca = array(
  .....
    'types' => array(
        'theme_section_columns' => array(
            'showitem' => '
                --palette--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_ttc.xlf:palette.general;general,
                --palette--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_ttc.xlf:palette.headers;header,
                tx_theme_tt_content,
                --div--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_ttc.xlf:tabs.access,
                --palette--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_ttc.xlf:palette.visibility;visibility,
                --palette--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_ttc.xlf:palette.access;access,
                --div--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_ttc.xlf:tabs.extended,
            '
        ),
    .....
    'columns' => array(
      'tx_theme_tt_content' => array(
        'label' => 'LLL:EXT:theme/Resources/Private/Language/Backend.xlf:content_element',
        'config' => array(
          'type' => 'inline',
          'foreign_table' => 'tt_content',
          'foreign_field' => 'tx_theme_tt_content',
          'appearance' => array(
            'useSortable' => TRUE,
            'showSynchronizationLink' => TRUE,
            'showAllLocalizationLink' => TRUE,
            'showPossibleLocalizationRecords' => TRUE,
            'showRemovedLocalizationRecords' => FALSE,
            'expandSingle' => TRUE,
            'enabledControls' => array(
              'localize' => TRUE,
            ),
          ),
          'behaviour' => array(
            'localizationMode' => 'select',
            'mode' => 'select',
            'localizeChildrenAtParentLocalization' => TRUE,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Everything works as expected, except one thing. In backend list module all tt_content elements are shown, including the children of theme_section_columns.
Is there a way to hide in the list module, the content elements which have a value in tx_theme_tt_content field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The listmod extension does what I want: 
http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/listmod